# Execution of a Python Script from PHP

Tags: php, android, python, linux, exec

I am making an android application in which I am first uploading the image to the server and on the server side, I want to execute a Python script from PHP. But I am not getting any output. When I access the Python script from the command prompt and run `python TestCode.py` it runs successfully and gives the desired output. I'm running Python script from PHP using the following command:

`$result = exec('/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/Source/TestCode.py');`

`echo $result`

However, if I run a simple Python program from PHP it works.

PHP has the permissions to access and execute the file.

Is there something which I am missing here?

Comment: exec doesn't print by itself, it will *return* the last line of output or it will put all lines of output into the second parameter (if provided), as the manual page would have told you ;o/

Comment: I modified it and still the problem is there. Any suggestions??

Comment: do you by any chance know the difference between stderr and stdout? because exec - as far as I know - only handles stdout. If your testcode.py only produces stderr output, you'll see nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
exec('/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/Source/TestCode.py', $output);

var_dump($output);
```

2nd Parameter of [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) will give output

**EDIT:**

```
exec('/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/Source/TestCode.py 2>&1', $output);
```

`2>&1` - redirecting `stderr` to `stdout`. Now in case of any error too, `$output` will be populated.

Comment: I received the output `array(0) {}`, which means that my array is empty but when I am running the python script it gives me the output.

Answer (score 1):

1. First Check your python PATH using "which python" command and check result is /usr/bin/python.
2. Check your "TestCode.py" if you have written #!/usr/bin/sh than replace it with #!/usr/bin/bash.
3. Than run these commands 
   exec('/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/Source/TestCode.py', $result);
   echo $result

Comment: I didn't get any output.

Comment: Ok just send your TestCode.py file, than let me try my best.